# Free abelian groups and abelian categories

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Why is the category of free abelian groups not an abelian category?

Comment: I don't think it has cokernels.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat A concrete example? One may think that the **FrAb** cokernel is somehow the torsion free part of the **Ab** cokernel. So writing something like $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$ as quotient of free abelian groups may lead to a case of nonexisting cokernel ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I was actually thinking of the map Mariano describes, but I didn't want to check explicitely wether it has no cokernel in the category of free abelian groups, instead I just assumed it would have to be the same as in the category of groups. I didn't bother to check.

Comment: Although that looks like a non-example, as there are no non trivial maps from $\Bbb Z$ to a free abelian group that vanish on the even integers.

Comment: @Olivier: the cokernel is trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The map $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ given by multiplication by $2$ is a mono and an epi, but not an iso.